# "Ich weiß es erscheint seltsam" - is the word order correct?

Tags: word-order

Does `erscheint` go to the end of the clause, or does it switch places with `es` to be the second idea?

Comment: You forgot the comma, otherwise it's fine. Here are all alternatives: "Ich weiß, es erscheint seltsam." – "Ich weiß, seltsam erscheint es." – "Ich weiß, dass es seltsam erscheint." – "Seltsam erscheint es, ich weiß." – "Es erscheint seltsam, ich weiß." – "Dass es seltsam erscheint, weiß ich." ... I'm sure someone else will give explanations ;)

Comment: What "second idea" are you talking about?

Comment: *Seltsam erscheint es, ich weiß* is valid, but it sounds a bit like Yoda speak to my ears ;) *Seltsam es erscheint, ich weiß! (caution, no good German)

Answer (score 8):

Put the comma in and you're perfectly fine.

> Ich weiß`,` es erscheint seltsam.

It's two sentences: 'ich weiß' and 'es erscheint seltsam'. Two main clauses linked by a comma, the verb goes in second place both times.

Answer (score 4):

The word order is correct (note the missing comma as mentioned in the other answers.)
This is an [unintroduced subordinate clause](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/index.html?MenuId=Sentence60&lang=en). In its introduced form (e.g. introduced by the subordinating conjunction `dass`), the word order would switch to the following:

> Ich weiß, dass es seltsam erscheint.

In this case the two forms can be used interchangeably. The only slight shift to the meaning that I would see is that the introduced form emphasizes the fact that you *know* that its strange.

Answer (score 2):

You can perfectly translate word for word:

> I know, it appears odd.
>   Ich weiß, es erscheint seltsam.

- I = Ich
- know = weiß
- it = es
- appears = erscheint
- odd = seltsam

Hopefully it is what you where looking for.
Otherwise, the answers ot the others look pretty well too.